# React: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'localeCompare' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, autocomplete, react-router, material-ui, react-router-dom

I'm building an app where I have a `Home` page where I render data that I'm getting from an API in the form of cards, and a `Favorites` page, where the cards marked as favorite are displayed. I'm using React Router, and I have a `Topbar` component with a `Nav` and a `Search`, the latter is utilizing the [grouped materialui autocomplete component](https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/#grouped).

In the `Search` component I'm trying to check whether the user is in the homepage or in the favorites page, in order to use 2 different arrays. The original array of data for the homepage, and the one with the favorited items for the favorites page and I'm getting the above error. I'm passing both arrays as props, and the search component initially worked with the original `beers` array. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, the error message is not helping me to identify the problem.

This is the logic that I wrote to differentiate among the pages:

```
let options;
  document.location.pathname === '/favorites'
    ? (options = favoriteBeers)
    : (options = beers);
```

And this is the code for the autocomplete component:

```
 options.map(option => {
    const firstLetter = option.name[0].toUpperCase();
    return {
      firstLetter: /[0-9]/.test(firstLetter) ? '0-9' : firstLetter,
      ...option,
    };
  });

<Autocomplete
        options={options.sort(
          (a, b) => -b.firstLetter.localeCompare(a.firstLetter)
        )}
        groupBy={option => option.firstLetter}
        getOptionLabel={option => option.name}
        getOptionSelected={(option, value) => option.id === value.id}
        clearOnEscape
        style={{ width: 400, margin: 'auto' }}
        onChange={(e, value) => handleOpen(value)}
        renderInput={params => (
          <TextField {...params} placeholder='Search for beer...' />
        )}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

map returns a new array, this way you should assign its return value to some variable. also you should always spread your object first, otherwise it may overwrite the changes you are performing:

```
options = options.map(option => {
    const firstLetter = option.name[0].toUpperCase();
    return {
      ...option,
      firstLetter: /[0-9]/.test(firstLetter) ? '0-9' : firstLetter,

    };
  });
```